# Capture function return value invoked by command

Tags: function, vim, command

Given the following, how can I invoke the command and capture the return value of the function (from vimscript, not command mode):

```
function! lib#stuff(one, two, ...)
  if a:0 == 1
    let l:three = a:1
  else
    let l:three = 'NULL'
  endif

  return a:one . a:two . l:three
endfunction!

command! -nargs=+ Stuff call lib#stuff(<f-args>)

" Does not work:
let result = Stuff '1', '2', '3'
echom Stuff '1', '2', '3'
```

Comment: why can't you just `let result = lib#stuff(...)` ? what 's your purpose ?

Comment: At the moment - learning more than anything else. I can call the function that way and it does work, however I'm trying to see if it's possible to use it via a command (just because). I'm sure there must be a way, but `:h user-commands` doesn't describe it.

Comment: You cannot use a command in an expression. So the syntax `let result = Stuff...` and `echom Stuff ...` is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

With command line command, you cannot get value returned by your function.

However if you really need catch the return value from the function you called in custom command and do some other work, there are ways: (assume the function with return value cannot be changed):

- write a wrapper function, from there you call the function with return value, and do some work with it.
- If you want to read the return value after execution of the command, you can in your wrapper function (or concatenated statements in :command) assign the return value to some buffer/global variable, thus after user executing the command, he can get the "return value" from the variable.
- If you want to just show the return value, just in your `:command` do `echo lib#stuff(....)` E.g. `:command! XY echo string(7*7)`  this will echo `49`